# $.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

I am getting following error when trying to run my website,

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

I am not well aware of javascript, hence i dont know what all this code does :

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){

var url = window.location.hash.replace("#/", "");

if(url != ""){

    setHashChange(true);

} else {

    iniMenuSlide("home");

}

});
```

Please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Comment: Well did you include the jQuery library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste below line in your page's head tag, preferably before any javascript linking or code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

The error is coming because you are not linking jQuery file or linking to older version, which is not supporting *on* function.

Answer (score 3):

The [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method was introduced in jQuery 1.7 (which is pretty ancient these days). Since you don't seem to have it, you need to upgrade to a more recent version of jQuery.

The code calls one of two different functions depending on if the URL has changed to one with fragment identifier at the end or not.